# Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, America/Chicago] and datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

Is there a difference in dtype=datetime64[ns, America/Chicago] and datetime64? I'm not sure why the follow code will not work:

```
start1 = np.datetime64('2023-01-29 17:00:00')
end1 = np.datetime64('2023-01-30 16:00:00')

df = df.loc[(df['time'] > start1) & (df['time'] < end1)]
```

It gives an error: TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, America/Chicago] and datetime64

Any suggestions? Should I try to convert the whole df['time'] series into datetime64? Originally I tried to convert the series to the pd.Timestamp datatype but I had issues there as well.

This might be a separate question but why did this not work?

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
```

This turned the datatype into an object instead of a Timestamp:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].values.astype(pd.Timestamp)
```

Any idea why it turned it into an object and this is probably an issue for plotting?

Comment: They are indeed two different types, [one](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64tz_dtype.html?highlight=datetime#pandas.api.types.is_datetime64tz_dtype) is timezone aware, the [other](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype.html?highlight=datetime#pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype) is not

Comment: you can use timezone-aware timestamps; e.g. `start1 = pd.Timestamp('2023-01-29 17:00:00', tz="America/Chicago")`